# how to represent polyhedron in voxel grid differentiably

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I am looking for a differentiable algorithm that would:
given set of points create a consistent polyhedron with those points as vertices - so for example polyhedron with maximal volume or any other consistent rule will give always the same polyhedron given the same set of points. Polyhedron should be indicated in a voxel grid - so for example all voxels inside the polyhedron should be set to 0.99 and all outside to 0.001 in entries of the 3d array representing the voxel grid. In general, the vertices will not lay on the grid hence a need for some interpolation.

There will be multiple polyhedrons generated.

Thanks for help!

Comment: *"for example polyhedron with maximal volume or any other consistent rule will give always the same polyhedron given the same set of points"* <<< Likely such a rule can work in most cases, but wouldn't work in some edge-cases. A simple example, imagine you have 7 points, 6 of which are the vertices of a cube, and the 7th is the centre of the cube. Then no matter your exact rule, there are probably 6 distinct polyhedrons that would work, and they would all be symmetric of each other.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "differentiable algorithm"?

Comment: as to consistence, i Understand still in practice I suppose it could work, by diferentiable I mean it would be a part of the optimization pipeline that is based on gradient descent